# (Python 2.7) Syntax error when trying to append string to list

Tags: python, syntax-error, global-variables

Heyo! I'm editing a script I found online that is written in Python 2.7. I've only ever coded in 3.8 so I'm not entirely familiar with the changes. Also still a beginner in Python 3.8

I've added some code to append a string to a list, but it throws me this syntax error whenever I try to run the script:[image: SyntaxError]
Here's the snippet of the code it refers to:

```
for r in range(0,self.__length):
        for c in range(0,self.__width):
            if self.__map[r][c] in (WALL,PERM_WALL):
                print '#'
                global mapdatalist.append("#")
            else:
                print '.'
                global mapdatalist.append(".")
```

It's referring to the `mapdatalist.append("#")` bit.
I've read the part on list functions [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html), and from what I'm reading I'm doing it right.
Anyone who is more experienced with this can help me out? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you expect `global mapdatalist.append("#")` to mean?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine a `global` declaration with an expression like that. Use `global mapdatalist` once, at the beginning of the function, and then use `mapdatalist` normally (e.g. `mapdatalist.append("#")`). (This is the same whichever version of Python you're using.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to append a string to the global variable `mapdatalist`,
you should declare the global variable before using the variable.

Try this:

```
global mapdatalist
for r in range(0,self.__length):
        for c in range(0,self.__width):
            if self.__map[r][c] in (WALL,PERM_WALL):
                print '#'
                mapdatalist.append("#")
            else:
                print '.'
                mapdatalist.append(".")
```